# How to change the icon for confirmation dialogs and alerts in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Using **dialogIcon(_:)** method gives me an Error: *"Value of type 'some View' has no member 'dialogIcon'"*

[Official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/dialogicon(_:)) provide the example. But it looks like it's not recognized by the Swift compiler as a valid method for the View type:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isShowingDialog = false

var body: some View {
    Button("Delete items") {
        isShowingDialog = true
    }
    .confirmationDialog("Confirmation dialog title", isPresented: $isShowingDialog) {
        
        Button("My Action") { print("My action") }
    }
    .dialogIcon(Image())
}}
```

This is the confirmation dialog with the default icon:
[image: confirmation dialog with the default icon]

How can I use this method to configure the icon for confirmation dialogs and alerts?

Comment: Are you targeting **iOS**? Because the documentation states that `.dialogIcon` is only available for **watchOS**, **macOS** & **visionOS**.

Comment: MacOS Deployment Target- macOS 13.1

Comment: Make sure you are using Xcode 15 Beta

Comment: But the only requirement is macOS 13.0+

Comment: @loremipsum Have you tried to run on Xcode 15 Beta?

Comment: I door think that matters, I made that comment because the majority of the people that ask questions about Beta software are not using Xcode Beta.

Comment: @loremipsum its not Beta on macOS 13.0+

Comment: @VityaShurapov If this is not for iOS, please update your tags.

Comment: Upgrading to xcode 15.1 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

From an app I'm developing

```
.dialogIcon(Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle"))
```

[Link to image of resulting dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0chOt.png)

Comment: For this type of dialog I'd recommend using `.dialogSeverity(.critical)`. On macOS, for example, this will display the standard critical alert style icon. It has an exclamation mark inside a yellow triangle, with a smaller version of the app icon in the bottom-right.